# Why doesn't printf work when piped in Bash?

Tags: c, bash, printf

I have a Bash script `work.sh` that get something from **STDIN** and echo it to **STDOUT**.

I also have a C programme, `return_input`, that also get something from **STDIN** and printf to **STDOUT**

But when I chain them this way:

```
./work.sh |./return_input
```

`printf` in `return_input` only output to screen when exiting. Why?

Simplified:

```
[root@ test]# cat work.sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..5}
do
   echo test
   read
done
```

Output of `cat return_input.c`,

```
#include <stdio.h>

void return_input (void){
    char array[30];
    gets (array);
    printf("%s\n", array);
    printf("%#p\n", *(long *)(array+40));
}

main() {
    while(1 == 1)return_input();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @James,When is flush necessary?

Comment: Is it just me, or is return_input just reading *once* and work.sh writing things as it goes along?  Seems like return_input should be reading work.sh's output in some kind of loop.

Comment: @clintp,I've modified the code now:)

Answer (score 5):

All I/O operations are usually buffered. This is why you get the output only after you program finishes if there are not much data to overflow the buffer and output during the execution.

You can use `fflush` function which forces to finish I/O operation and clear buffers if you want to see output in the "real time"

Answer (score 1):

You should post some code.

Try making sure that the output is flushed (using `fflush(stdout);` in C after you've written to it), and/or that the text contains line-feeds since typically those force the output to be flushed.

Otherwise the output might be "stuck" in a buffer, which is an optimization rather than sending single bytes across the pipeline between the processes.

Comment: "When opened, a stream is fully buffered if and only if it can be determined not to refer to an interactive device." (C90). STDOUT should be an interactive device and the flush happening at least at each `\n`.

Comment: I've provided a simplified example above:)

Comment: "Forcing" may be done by the 'stdbuf' utility. See 'man stdbuf'.

Comment: But seems in my case it's buffered by `work.sh`,not in c programe?